# Please suggest some resources from which explain silver-light business application in detail

Tags: silverlight, resources

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee796239%28v=vs.91%29.aspx#Y3078

but, i am hobbyist (small time :) ) i dont understand every thing provided in these tutorials,

- please suggest some online links which explain each and everything used in great and simple detail.
- please provide some references to good books which also do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This book](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430272076) is a good reference for business applications developers with Silverlight

[image]